# Slick - First Example - Where do I get the jar containing the "Database" package?

Tags: scala, slick

So now that I've finally decided to give slick a shot, I'm stuck on the first example.

http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.1/gettingstarted.html#populating-the-database

In the guide, the following code is used  to connect to an H2 database:

```
import scala.slick.driver.H2Driver.simple._
import Database.threadLocalSession

Database.forURL("jdbc:h2:mem:test1", driver = "org.h2.Driver") withSession {
  // The session is never named explicitly. It is bound to the current
  // thread as the threadLocalSession that we imported
}
```

I just don't understand what `Database` is.  Is it a library I can download somewhere?  Where?

Please, grease my rusty wheels so I can get rolling with slick!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Database` is the companion object of the class `scala.slick.session.Database`. Here are its [docs](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.1/api/index.html#scala.slick.session.Database).

In case you are puzzled by the imports, the `H2Driver.simple` has an reference to this object which is also named `Database`.

Btw, a quick clarification regarding your comments in the other answer:

- The `"jdbc:h2:mem:test1"` url will create a new memory database. So, even if you have an H2 instance running, using this url won't connect to it.
- If you are using SBT (or Maven -- but the scala community prefer to ignore maven), you don't need another H2 installation. Even if you plan to keep your data between runs, you can use the "file database mode" from H2, or even start a server from another java process. eg. In a project I worked, I used SBT to invoke the H2 Server starting commands.

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing: That was it.  I just needed to `import scala.slick.session.Database`.  Thanks.

Comment: That's odd. Check that out http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.1/api/index.html#scala.slick.driver.BasicProfile$SimpleQL. It has a val named `Database` and should have been enabled by your first import.

Comment: I meant for version 1.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running v2.0.0? Because it doesn't have any docs yet. I did exactly this yesterday and hit your problem. It seems `Database` is not in v2. I couldn't find sample code that would work with v2. Try your existing code but depend on `"com.typesafe.slick" % "slick_2.10" % "1.0.1"` instead, at least for now.